# Magento 2: How to Change fieldset accordion in product edit page to tab in backend?

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, adminform

I have a lot of product attribute set in the backend , and it  is not convenient to scroll all the way down to edit product page information, How can i change the accordion in the product edit backend to tab in Magento 2 just like in Magento 1 ?

Answer (score 1):

By **Attribute Sets**

If you want to rearrange your attributes then use **attribute sets**. You can also group them in to accordion, according to your Preferences. Or can push it to Unassigned Attributes, if it's not in use.

For **Attribute Set:**

Go to > Admin > Stores > Attributes > Attribute Sets > Select the Attribute Set

[image: By clicking on Add new Group into it.]

[image: Like this you rearrange & Drag-and-Drop the attribute]

Then just drag and Drop the Attribute.

If it helps then please let me know.

Thanks

Sid